# WPF Storyboard does not pause

Tags: wpf, storyboard

I have a very simple Storyboard with an Int32Animation that targets a custom DP on my class.

I have an OnChanged callback for my DP, that does a Console.WriteLine("Current Value: " + MyDP).

When I run the storyboard, I can see the Console output just fine, and when I pause the storyboard, the Console output stops, BUT, when I resume the storyboard, the DP is NOT the next value at it should be. It continues increasing even though the storyboard has stopped.

Has anyone had anything like this happen to them?

here is a code snippet of what Im doing

```
            Int32Animation element = new Int32Animation();
            element.From = 0;
            element.To = targetTo;
            element.Duration = dur;
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(element, new PropertyPath(CurrentFrameProperty));
            _filmstripStoryboard = new Storyboard {SpeedRatio = this.FrameRate};
            _filmstripStoryboard.Children.Add(element);


        public void Start()
        {
            _filmstripStoryboard.Begin(this, true);
        }

        public void Pause()
        {
            _filmstripStoryboard.Pause(this);
        }

        public void Unpause()
        {
            _filmstripStoryboard.Resume(this);
        }
```

Comment: Is there a trigger in XAML code for beginning the storyboard ?

Comment: no nothing like that I dont think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [thread in the MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/d2517850-81cc-4d22-be7d-cad522540ad2) where Microsoft confirms that this behavior (the current value continuing even when the storyboard is paused for a while) is a bug in the then-current (as of 2006) release of WPF. The forum thread includes a suggested workaround, specifically, save off the current position when you pause, and manually seek back to that same position when you resume.

The thread mentions that they were thinking about fixing the bug in a future version, but I do not know whether .NET 3.5 or 4.0 actually fixed this bug or not.

**EDIT:** It appears that the bug is fixed in .NET 4.0 -- I was able to pause and then resume an animation without it jumping forward across the intervening time. (I didn't test in 3.5.)

Answer (score 0):

Now there is no bug in 4.0 . Below code works fine.

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Class="WpfAnimation.Win1805787"
    xmlns:Local="clr-namespace:WpfAnimation"
    x:Name="MyWindow"
    Title="Win1805787"
    Width="640" Height="480">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">      

        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Text="{Binding CurrentFrame, ElementName=MyWindow}" Height="20" Margin="5,0,5,5"/>
            <Button x:Name="Play1" Content="Play" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Play_Click" Margin="5,0,5,5"/>
            <Button x:Name="Pause1" Content="Pause" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Pause_Click" Margin="5,0,5,5"/>
            <Button x:Name="Resume1" Content="Resume" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Resume_Click" Margin="5,0,5,5"/>
        </StackPanel>

        </Grid>

</Window>
```

/////////////////////////

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Data;
    using System.Windows.Documents;
    using System.Windows.Input;
    using System.Windows.Media;
    using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
    using System.Windows.Shapes;
    using System.Windows.Media.Animation;

    namespace WpfAnimation
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Interaction logic for Win1805787.xaml
        /// </summary>
        public partial class Win1805787 : Window
        {
            public Win1805787()
            {
                this.InitializeComponent();

                _createStoryBoard();
                // Insert code required on object creation below this point.
            }

            public int CurrentFrame
            {
                get { return (int)GetValue(CurrentFrameProperty); }
                set { SetValue(CurrentFrameProperty, value); }
            }

            // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for CurrentFrame.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
            public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentFrameProperty =
                DependencyProperty.Register("CurrentFrame", typeof(int), typeof(Win1805787), 
                        new PropertyMetadata(0, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnValueChanged)));

            private static void OnValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
            {

            }

            Storyboard _filmstripStoryboard;

            void _createStoryBoard()
            {       
                Int32Animation element = new Int32Animation();
                element.From = 0;
                element.To = 100;
                element.Duration = Duration.Plus(new Duration(new TimeSpan(1000000000)));
                Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(element, new PropertyPath(CurrentFrameProperty));
                _filmstripStoryboard = new Storyboard { SpeedRatio = 0.5 };
                _filmstripStoryboard.Children.Add(element);
            }

            private void Play_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                _filmstripStoryboard.Begin(this, true);
            }

            private void Pause_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                _filmstripStoryboard.Pause(this);
            }

            private void Resume_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                _filmstripStoryboard.Resume(this);
            }

        }
    }
```